# overflow-x on html element and ios

Tags: html, css

I've been pulling my hair out looking for this answer and I just can't find it anywhere.

Here's the issue:  I am trying to create a mobile navigation menu for a project I am working on.  I am trying to prevent a scroll over when the `#siteWrapper` is moved left via JavaScript.

I am currently testing my code in iOS simulator.  Here is the CSS I am using:

```
html, body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}

#siteWrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: 250px;
}
```

While this works, the problem is that it kills the native scrolling in iOS, which forces you to have to add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to put back in the scrolling.  While that's also fine, it messes with fixed elements that are on the site... Such as a header.  It jumps around because `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` handles touch events differently than it would natively.

I know this can work because I have seen it done in other plugins.  I have looked high and low for an answer and I am just not sure how to fix this.

Any thoughts??

Comment: What's a "scroll over"? Do you mean you're trying to prevent the site from being scrollable?

Comment: When the `siteWrapper` scrolls over to the right, to prevent scrolling over to the right.

Comment: Hm, sorry I'm still not sure what you mean. Maybe I just don't understand because I don't have an iPhone. :D